# Can't display list on Activity

Tags: android, xml, android-activity, android-studio

I'm trying to display a ListView of locations after reading the data from a text file, I have created a custom adapter and a new activity bu when I open the activity, I only get a white screen.

Here is the code of the adapter I added :

```js
public class LocationAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private List<Location> Locations;
        int monLayout;
        LayoutInflater inflater;


        public LocationAdapter(Context context, int layout){
            monLayout=layout;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            Locations = new ArrayList<Location>();
        }



        private class Location{
            public String name;
            public String address;
            public Long date;

            public Location(String _name,String _address , Long _date){
                name=_name;
                address=_address;
                date=_date;

            }
        }


        private class ViewHolder{

            TextView name_view;
            TextView address_view;
            TextView date_view;

            public ViewHolder(View rowLayout){

                name_view = (TextView)rowLayout.findViewById(R.id.name);
                date_view = (TextView)rowLayout.findViewById(R.id.date);
                address_view = (TextView)rowLayout.findViewById(R.id.address);
            }
        }

        public void addLocation(String _name,String _address,Long _date){
            //Création d'une nouvelle location avec les données en paramètres
            Location new_loc = new Location(_name, _address,_date);

            //Ajout de la location à la liste des locations
            Locations.add(new_loc);

        }
    /*Méthodes de la classe mère*/

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return 0;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            View view = convertView;

            if (view == null)
                view = inflater.inflate(monLayout, parent, false);

            ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder)view.getTag();
            if (holder == null)
            {
                holder = new ViewHolder(view);
                view.setTag(holder);
            }

            Location location = (Location)getItem(position);

            holder.name_view.setText(location.name);
            holder.address_view.setText(location.address);
            holder.date_view.setText("Test");

            return view;
        }
}
```

Here is the code of the Oncreate method of my Activity :

```js
  public class SortedLocationsListActivity extends ListActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            //setContentView(R.layout.activity_sorted_locations_list);


            InputStream is = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.locations);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            List<String> maListe = new ArrayList<String>();
            String myligne;
            LocationAdapter adapter = new LocationAdapter(this, R.layout.row_location);

            try {
                while((myligne = in.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    String a[] = myligne.split(";");
                    Long _date=Long.parseLong(a[2], 36);
                    System.out.println(a[0]+" "+a[1]+" "+a[2]);
                    adapter.addLocation(a[0],a[1],_date);
                }
                setListAdapter(adapter);

            }
            catch(IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Error");
            }

        }
```

Here is the XML of the layout I want to use for each element of the list :

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Faculté de Droit"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="7 nov. 2014"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>
    <TextView android:id="@+id/address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="41 Boulevard François Mitterand, Clermont-Ferrand"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fix your adapter:

```
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Locations.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return Locations.get(position);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `getCount()` is returning 0 in your `adapter`. Should return:

```
Locations.size();
```

Answer (score 0):

To understand listview's and optimising them read http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/

The fix for your issue is below but you also may want to optimise your getView() method (done below).

The adapter is currently returning getCount() as 0, meaning it is telling the listview there is nothing to show. This should be the size of your list.

The adapter is also returning null for getItem, so in your getView() method, you would get a null pointer when calling location.name. getItem() should return Locations.get(position).

```
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Locations.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return Locations.get(position);
    }   

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(monLayout, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        }

        Location location = (Location) getItem(position);

        holder.name_view.setText(location.name);
        holder.address_view.setText(location.address);
        holder.date_view.setText("Test");

        return view;
    }
```